# using an int * (array) return value in python via cffi?

Tags: python, python-cffi

I have a C function

```
int * myfunc()
{
   int * ret = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
   ...
   return ret;
}
```

in python I can call it as

```
ret = lib.myfunc()
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to actually use ret in the python code (i.e. cast it to an int array of length 5.

I see lots of documentation (and questions here) about how to pass a python array into a C function, but not how one deals with an array returned from a C function.

the only thing I've figured out so far (which sort of works, but seems ugly)

```
buf = ffi.buffer(ret,ffi.sizeof("int")*5)
int_array = ffi.from_buffer("int *", buf)
```

is that what I'm supposed to do? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, the type `int *` and the type `int[5]` are equivalent at runtime.  That means that although you get a `int *` from calling the function, you can directly use it as if it were a `int[5]`.  All the same operations work with the exception of `len()`.  For example:

```
ret = lib.myfunc()
my_python_list = [ret[i] for i in range(5)]
lib.free(ret)    # see below
```

As the function called `malloc()`, you probably need to call `free()` yourself, otherwise you have a memory leak.  Declare it by adding the line `void free(void *);` to the `cdef()` earlier.

There are some more advanced functions whose usage is optional here: you could cast the type from `int *` to `int[5]` with `p = ffi.cast("int[5]", p)`; or instead you could convert the C array into a Python list with an equivalent but slightly faster call `my_python_list = ffi.unpack(ret, 5)`.